# ASP.Net MVC 3 Querystring Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, query-string

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 Web Application. Within some of my Views I display tabular data to the user, and beside each record in the table there is an Edit link. When the user clicks this link it takes them to an edit page where they can edit and update the record.

My issue is that once the user clicks the edit link, the URL becomes something like this

```
http://www.mytestsite.com/myData/edit/3
```

The '3' is the ID of the record to be updated, however, there is nothing stopping the user from changing the '3' to another digit, and this then means they can edit potentially a record which does not belong to them.

Does anyone have a solution on how I can prevent this from happening?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to introduce Authentication and Authorisation into your application. [Here is one article of many out there on how to get started with this](http://bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0). You will additionally need to work out how to store logged on user identity and then how to attach this to the record when it was created in the first place. You must then validate, on the server, that the subsequent edit request is being made by the user who created the record in the first place (or by a user who has a role on your system which allows them to do this, such as an Administrator).

Even if the ID wasn't being displayed on the URL a malicious user could still manipulate the HTTP Request to pass an ID  of their choice. In any secure system you should always, always, always validate that the currently logged on user genuinely has permission to carry out the requested action. You should never rely on what comes back from the browser to determine this (aside from the authentication context which is managed securely by the MVC framework. Usually).

Comment: Holf, I agree. I need to implement the logic to ensure that the user who is trying to edit the record, is the same user who created it. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should have the information about who have the edit permission on this purticular resource, in your tables. Ex : in your table you might have the "`CreatedById`" column where you store the ID of the user who created this record. Now in your edit action method, you check the "`CreatedById`" of the current Item is same as of the "`UserId`" of the Current user (you maye get this from the session, if you stored it there). Something like this.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  int currentUserID=1; // TO DO : get this value from session or somewhere

  ProductVieWModel product=myRepo.GetProduct(id);

  if(product!=null)
  {
     if(product.CreatedById==currentUserID)
     {
        return View(product);
     }
     else
     {
        return View("NotAutherized");
     }
  }
  return View("ProdcutNotFound");

}
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju, this is useful.

Answer (score -1):

You should try using the GUID data type as it helps in these kind of situations, and the user cannot easily guess the next value